# JWT decode React

Tags: json, reactjs, jwt, token

Hello everyone i want to use jwt decode in my react project but when i want to console.log decoded token it shows me errors

the token is fine because the authetication works fine i don't know the problem
this is my code

```
async formSubmit(ev){
    ev.preventDefault()
    const {username, password} = this.state
    try {
        const token = await Axios.post("api/login/", {username, password})
        localStorage.setItem("token", token)
        this.setState({
            loggedIn: true
        })
      var jwtDecode = require('jwt-decode')

      var decoded = jwtDecode(token)
      console.log(decoded)
    } catch (err) {
        this.setState({
            error: "compte inexistant"
        })
    }
}
```

and this is the error [image]

Comment: Can you verify you are not failing on `this.setState...`?

Comment: everything works fine the authentication works fine i get some warnings not related to the login form but i can't console.log the decoded token

Comment: when i console log my token i get the access token and the refresh token and i can decode them with an online decoder to see the result but when i use jwt decode in react it doen't show anything in console log

Comment: how do you debug? chrome? with the react developer tools?

try `console.log(JSON.stringify(decoded));` ?

you are missing `;` in your code ... that's your coding style? (not a must in JS, but recommended)

Comment: @ShaharHadas `;` is a matter of preference only, there is no such thing as recommended to use  `;`. there is only  specific corner cases where you need to use `;`, but that's not the case.

Comment: @buzatto I disagree, but it is a personal preference.
In any case - how does your comment adds to the resolution of the issue?

Answer (score 1):

it's working now i don't know why actually but it's working here's the code :

```
 formSubmit(ev){
    const {username, password} = this.state
    ev.preventDefault();
    Axios.post("api/login/", {username, password}).then(res => 
    {localStorage.setItem("token", JSON.stringify(res.data.access))
    let decoded = jwt_decode(localStorage.getItem("token"))
     localStorage.setItem('decoded',decoded)
    console.log(decoded)
        this.setState({
            loggedIn: true
        });
   }).catch(e =>{
     this.setState({
            error: "compte inexistant"
        })
   })
```

Comment: if anyone knows why tell me please xD